# Migration to Spring 6

Tags: spring

I am trying to migrate to Spring 6 and I am getting stuck with following error:

```
Class org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider does not implement the requested interface jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1797) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1747) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    ... 58 more
```

I checked and `SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider` implements `org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider` which certainly implements `jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider`.

I checked and there does not seem to be other versions on the classpath and also from the stacktrace you can see  `~[spring-orm-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]` which means the current version should be correctly used. Where can I search for the error?

Comment: Please share your pom.xml

Answer (score 2):

This was caused by propagated dependency through `c3p0`:

```kotlin
implementation("org.hibernate:hibernate-core-jakarta:5.6.14.Final")
implementation("org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:5.6.14.Final") {
    // propagates unwanted hibernate-core module
    exclude(group = "org.hibernate", module = "hibernate-core")
}
```